# Dataframe - groupby access previous to previous record in the groupedDataSet

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario, where I need to compute `PreviousPolicyNo` based on `PolicyNo`. The data first needs to be sorted on the basis of `TransactionDate`. Then, we will have to check that if such a `PolicyTerm` was available before or not, if so, take latest available `PolicyNo` (available prior to `TransactionDate`) from that record and make entry to `PreviousPolicyNo`. If such a `PolicyTerm` was not available in the past, then pick the latest `PolicyNo` available (so far) or mark the entry as null if no previous term exist earlier (first row).

For example,

[image]

To calculate, second last entry, I had to look for last value available so far (prior to 12-12-2014) for `PolicyTerm` - 2 and similarly, for last entry, I had to look for last record available (prior to 12-12-2014) with `PolicyTerm` 3.

I need help for Scala implementation, I implemented an `UDF` (where I collected these columns in a `List[Struct]`), but it is not working good with huge dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions can be used since they allow for both partitioning and sorting. However, the two conditions would need separate window functions. Below `w1` corresponds to the condition where the same `PolicyTerm` have occured before (hence partitioned by `PolicyTerm`), `w2` on the other hand picks the latest `PolicyNo` regardless of the `PolicyTerm`.

```
val w1 = Window.partitionBy("PolicyTerm").orderBy("TransactionDate")
val w2 = Window.orderBy("TransactionDate")

val df2 = df.withColumn("LagGroupPolicyNo", lag($"PolicyNo", 1).over(w1))
  .withColumn("LagPolicyNo", lag($"PolicyNo", 1).over(w2))
  .withColumn("PreviousPolicyNo", coalesce($"LagGroupPolicyNo", $"LagPolicyNo"))
  .drop("LagGroupPolicyNo", "LagPolicyNo")
```

Comment: Could you suggest what changes I need to make if I have to deal here with multiple PolicyID.

Comment: @Sandeep: That should be very simple, simply partition by `PolicyID` in both windows. Change to: `val w1 = Window.partitionBy("PolicyID", "PolicyTerm").orderBy("TransactionDate")` and `val w2 = Window.partitionBy("PolicyID").orderBy("TransactionDate")`.